# Search from end of string and split

Tags: python

I am parsing a large DBF file to import into mongodb.

One of the fields in the DBF file is called `Description` and this is like

```
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - MELANGE GREY - S
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - MELANGE GREY - M
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT - WHITE- L
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT- WHITE -XL
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT- WHITE -2XL
WOMEN'S CC CROPPED TOP T-SHIRT- WHITE -3XL
JUNIOR EP ORGANIC T-SHIRT - YELLOW- 3-4 YRS
JUNIOR EP ORGANIC T-SHIRT - YELLOW - 5-6 YRS
EP ORGANIC BIB - PINK -ONE SIZE
```

What will be the best way to split this so that I have the `product name`, `colour` and `size`?

in most cases, i can do :

```
try:
  description, colour_name, size = style_meta_attributes['CN_DESC'].split('- ')
  if colour_name not in colour_names:
    colour_names.append(colour_name)
  if size not in sizes_names:
    sizes_names.append(size)
except:
  try:
    description, colour_name, size = style_meta_attributes['CN_DESC'].split(' -')
 ...
```

for each `splits = [' - ', '- ', ' -', ' -', ' - ', '-']`

but this does work as when i have `T-SHIRT` or `3-4 YRS`

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
re.split(r'\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+', description)
```

The idea is to require whitespace before OR after the delimiter (or on both sides).